# Working with url and strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, url

I'm working with cordova 3.5

I've an iframe setup as following:

```
  <iframe src="http://localhost/test/index.html" style="width:100%;height:90%" onLoad="checkforclose(this);"></iframe>
```

And the JS is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkforclose(pageURL) { 
    var urlFrame = pageURL.contentWindow.location; //WORKS
    alert(urlFrame); //WORKS
    alert(urlFrame.indexOf('test')); //DOESN'T WORK EVEN FOR ANY VALUE - RETURNS UNDEFINED
}   
</script>
```

The snippet works, because the first two lines works. But the third don't.
Even more, in JSFiddler works.
I'm very lost with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you provide the jsfiddle link please?

Comment: yes but it won't work because the iframe is pointing to my localhost

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Zy3Q/20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try alert(urlFrame.href.indexOf('test'));

The reason it doesn't work is you are calling indexOf on a window.location (urlFrame) Object.  It is throwing an error because indexOf() is not a function property of window.location.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. You mean that: pageURL.contentWindow.location.indexOf doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. indexOf will only work on Arrays ( >IE8 ) and Strings

Comment: Even more, this was a Kobashi Maru to me, so easy for you and hard to solve to me :S I must have think out of the box more often.

Comment: I use the Chrome browsers developement tools to debug the JS you wrote.  This way I can see errors in the console and set breakpoints to debug the code.

Comment: I was blocked in the android emulator :S Bad for me. I'll begin to work as you

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var urlFrame = pageURL.src
```

You are getting undefined because value of "urlFrame" is empty.